# Modules missing in statsmodels (python, OaxacaBlinder)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda, statsmodels

I would like to use `OaxacaBlinder` package of `statsmodels`, as described [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.oaxaca.OaxacaBlinder.html). However I consistently encounter warnings:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OaxacaBlinder'
```

I didn't find any posts related to this specific attribute (most seem to use the equivalent packages in R), however there seems to be many questions about the `statsmodels` attributes missing due to incorrect installation of the package. I have tried reinstalling it with `conda` and `pip` without success (under python3).

I appreciate the advice regarding the correct installation OR the existence/functioning of the package.

Comment: Please also include in your question a minimal version of your code that produces the error and the full error traceback.

Comment: @cel I am just trying to reproduce the code in the link. Although I suspect it has some errors.

Comment: yes, the example code looks outdated. You can import `OaxacaBlinder` by using `from statsmodels.stats.oaxaca import OaxacaBlinder` - afterwards you would use it by `model = OaxacaBlinder(df.endog, df.exog, 3, hasconst = False)`

Comment: xref: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6899

Answer (score 1):

With statsmodels version 0.11.1, you should be able to run the example with following code:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> from statsmodels.stats.oaxaca import OaxacaBlinder

>>> data = sm.datasets.ccard.load() 

>>> model = OaxacaBlinder(data.endog, data.exog, 3, hasconst = False) 
>>> model.two_fold().summary()
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named oaxaca`

Comment: This works with statsmodel=0.11.1. You can check the version by `import statsmodels as sm` followed by `print(sm.__version__)`.